# Efficient method for opening and manipulating embedded OpenDocument Text File in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, embedded

I have an Excel Book for managing my customers information. It has a structure similar to this:
[image: Table]

The last column (Details) has an embed object (OpenDocument Text), which I use to put arbitrary information. If I select the object and press Enter it will go to **edit mode**; however to **Open** it, I need to Right Click and select Open under Document Object (which is inefficient).

[image: Right Click menu]

What I'm looking for is, either to change the default behavior, so that pressing Enter opens the document rather than going to edit mode. Or a convenient shortcut to **open** the embedded document.

The reason I'm putting those information in an embedded file is because it's totally arbitrary info that goes there (can be a few words or a more than 10 lines of text).

And the reason I'm not embedding a raw text file is I don't want the file icon to mess my table.

I welcome any other ideas that can help achieve the desired behavior, even if it means using a software other than Excel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedded object seems like overkill. You can store multi line text natively in a cell in multiple ways:

1. Type the first line in the cell, press alt+enter for the new line and proceed. Play with font size and text wrapping formatting to achieve the desired look.
2. Store the text inside a comment or note. Select any cell. Press SHIFT+F2 to edit or insert the comment. On the review tab, you can easily jump to next or previous comments using the arrows. Very convenient during editing or review.
3. Insert a textbox shape, double click to edit text. Size the textbox to fit the cell. Edit shape properties and set to resize and move with cell.

Answer (score 1):

#### What I'm looking for is ... a convenient shortcut to open the embedded document.

Once it is selected press <kbd>menu</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>.

See below for one example location of the <kbd>menu</kbd> key and what it may look like:

[image]